# Can class type be deduced from pointer to member function template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member, type-deduction, template-argument-deduction

Is it possible to deduce the type of the class `T` from its pointer to memmber `T::*f` as shown below.

```
struct Foo
{
    void func(){}
};

template<typename T, void (T::*f)()>
void bar()
{
}

int main()
{
    bar<Foo,Foo::func>();
    // bar<Foo::func>(); // Desired
}
```

Comment: You are not deducing anything, you are explicitly specifying the template parameters. You can deduce the template parameters using something like `template <class T> void bar(void (T::*f)()){/*do something with T*/}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++17, you will be allowed to write

```
template<auto M>
void bar();
```

Which allows

```
bar<&Foo::func>();
```

Comment: @skypjack Not quite. I'd like to 'name' the pointer to a member function without 'naming' the class to which it belongs so Jarod's recommendation works -- alas I'm restricted to C++03.

Comment: @Olumide Not a problem, I misunderstood the question. It happens. Anyway, if you are restricted to C++03, I suspect you have no chance but to pass it as a function argument. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 5):

In C++11/14 I would say no, unless you accept to deduce it by passing the pointer as a function argument:

```
template<typename T>
void bar(void(T::*f)())
{
}

int main()
{
    bar(&Foo::func);
}
```

In C++17 you can have a single parameter function template as shown by [@Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42840735/4987285), but you don't have the type `T` deduced anyway (if it was the purpose, as it seems to be from the question).

Comment: I know that but thanks anyway. Problem is that `Foo::func` has got to be a template parameter, which I am okay with, but I'd like to avoid identifying/naming `T`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to C++17, you can use `auto` template parameter and `decltype` to inspect the class type:

```
struct Foo { void func(){} };

template<typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
C function_pointer_class(R (C::*)(Args...));

template<auto f>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(f)>>
bar() {
    using class_t = decltype(function_pointer_class(f));

    // stuff...
}

int main() {
    bar<&Foo::func>();
}
```

Comment: Clever. +1 (even though OP is bound to C++03).

Comment: This one is an actual answer to this question as it solves stated problem (one which I was also looking for).